# Is this the correct use of a try/catch block

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I'm trying to decode URLs that may be single or double percent encoded using `decodeURIComponent()`. Because I don't want to get an `"URI malformed"` when a string is attempted to be decoded that only contains `%25` (5), I'm using this `try/catch` block. Have I used the `try/catch` block correctly? It seems to work, but I'm trying to understand if this is a best practice approach, or if I've over-complicated things.

```
var uriCleanup = function (str) {

    var cln = function (str) {

        try {

            str = decodeURIComponent(str);
            //try to decode the URI again
            return cln(str);

        } catch (e) {
           //if error thrown, URI contains single percent symbol
           //return the str as it was the last time it was decoded
           return str;

        }

    };

    return cln(str);

};
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wuvejuro/5/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do overcomplicate things: there's no need to use recursion here.

```
function uriCleanup(str) {
    var cln = str;
    try {
        do {
            cln = decodeURIComponent(str);
        } while (cln !== str && (str = cln));
    }
    catch (e) {}
    return cln;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I notice that you didn't remove the try/catch block. Do you think that is okay, or is there a way to do without, especially since nothing is being done in the catch statement.

Comment: Of course it's ok in this particular case; all the other means to prevent that pesky `URIError: malformed URI sequence` are worse by a mile. But in your original code each subsequent invocation of `cln` created their own try-catch scope, which was bad (as it wasn't really needed).

Comment: what is happening in this evaluation? `cln !== str && (str = cln)`.

Comment: @thomas First, `cln` (the result of decoding) is compared with the original string (stored in `str`). If they're identical, no further decoding change anything, so the loop breaks. If they're not, the result of decoding is stored in the `str` value, and the loop goes on to process it.

Comment: Thank you that's clear now. So in JavaScript evaluations you can include variable variable assignments after an `&&`? I was aware that a for-loop of course included this sort of declaration `for (var i = 0,len=myArray.length; i<len; i++`, but what is it called when you include it after the `&&` and it looks like part of the evaluation. Have you got a link to any documentation on this. Thanks so much.

Comment: @thomas Assignment is just an expression, so you can use it as part of another expression freely. Just remember that `=` operator's precedence is [one of the lowest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), so it's most likely you'll have to wrap assignment in parens - like in that example.

Comment: how does the `&&` work in that case? Why isn't a semicolon or something. `&&` seems to require that the following expression (the assignment) evaluate to `true`. I mean, yeah: `!!(1+1) //true`, but why is it necessary that `&&` _require_ it resolve to true. Or maybe I've missed something fundamental. Thanks again.

Comment: It works very similar to comma (sequence) operator, except one thing: `str = cln` will be evaluated only if `cln !== str` is `true`. The result of `str = cln` matters only if it's falsy value, but that's just not possible: if `cln` is an empty string (the only falsy value of String type in JS), `str` could only be an empty string too; hence the first expression is false too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not best practice. `try/catch` you should use, and only use, for handling exceptional situations that interrupt the flow of code and break your ability to complete it. If you use it more generally, you wind up with a very powerful `goto`-like structure with unwieldy use in your code.

try/catch is a harder structure to learn compared to if, else, while, etc., because it only really makes sense if you're working in a somewhat large code base, with modular library functions.

A simple example might be the function

```
var saveOrder = function(order) {
    if(!order.confirmed) {
        throw new Error("Please confirm you order.");
    }
    saveToMySQL(order);
};

//... somewhere else

try { 
    order = getOrderFromUser();
    saveOrder(userOrder);
    alert("Thank you for your order, continue shopping?");
}
catch(err) {
    alert(err);
}
```

The points here are

- `saveOrder` throws because it *cannot* proceed
- try/catch is *only* used by the method that believes it can handle the exception
- if *no* exception happens, the code reads linearly and cleanly, and the following line never has to worry about whether the previous line succeeded

Comment: This is a really nice explanation, thank you. I think that I don't see any other way to avoid the use of try/catch to avoid that error. If not try/catch, what do you suggest?

Comment: @thomas You can use try-catch, just only use it to handle exceptional exceptions, not to create clever control flows. raina77ow's answer is good.

Comment: Can you define "exceptional exceptions"? Thanks